# why do I encounter PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that will automatically update column) `totaltripsmade` on my table DRIVER. The trigger will fire when a trip record is inserted into my table TRIP.

To begin I have a set of trip records. I'm thinking of using count(*) on my `Licence#` in TRIP to update the `totaltripmade` in DRIVER as both tables have `Licence#`.

Below is my code

```
create or replace trigger UpdateTTM 
  after insert on trip 
  for each row 

BEGIN
  LOOP 
  UPDATE DRIVER     
  SET totalTripMade = (select Lic# as L, count (*) as TTM FROM TRIP GROUP BY Lic# HAVING Lic# = Lic#)
  WHILE Lic# = L;
  END LOOP; 

end UpdateTTM;
/
```

I am fairly new to SQL and I am unsure why I face this error of SQL command not properly ended. I hope there are people out there who can guide me through this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because this is not valid Oracle SQL syntax. Instead of guessing or making stuff up you should consult [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5) which is comprehensive, online and free. We can easily solve most compiler errors by comparing our code with the given examples.

But once you've fixed the UPDATE statement your trigger will hurl [the mutating table error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle%2Btrigger%2Bmutating%2Btable) because you're trying to select from TRIP in a trigger owned by TRIP and that's not allowed.

The simplest way to do this would be:

```
create or replace trigger UpdateTTM 
  after insert on trip 
  for each row 

begin

  update driver
  set totalTripMade = nvl(totalTripMade,0) + 1
  where driver.Lic# = :new.Lic#;

end UpdateTTM;
/
```

This assumes the DRIVER record exists before a TRIP record is created. If that's not the case you should address the hole in your data model before proceeding.

Also, the performance won't scale and you'll still have problems running it in multi-user environments. But those are only issues in the real world and this question smacks of the homework assignment.